# Issue while starting confluent-kafka service in Ubuntu

Tags: apache-kafka

While running confluent-kafka service in ubuntu, I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Receiver class scala.collection.mutable.HashSet$ must be the current class  
at scala.collection.IterableFactory.apply$(Factory.scala:103) 
at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.<init(VerifiableProperties.scala:28)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:33)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)  
 at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) 
 confluent-kafka.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
  confluent-kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS

JDK version: 11

Since I am new to the Kafka implementation, this is best possible way i could present the query. Do let me know in case of any further details required. Appreciate any guidance regarding the issue.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html Followed these steps

Comment: Just a small update......I am actually doing this activity in AWS EC2 terminal.......

Comment: I think you have Scala 2.11 installed, or some verison issue related to that

Comment: I Have not installed Scala explicitly with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed confluent-platform and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Though I installed confluent kafka I was getting the error "Error E:exit code 1."

I checked the java intallation.the `$JAVA_HOME` should be set to the java home dir . for eg: I installed java under `/home/mmk/jdk-17.0.7`.
so set this using

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mmk/jdk-17.0.7
```

and and also set the `PATH` using

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```